# C++ macros - holding keys for certain time

Tags: c++, macros

I just started with C++ and I want to make my game character being IDLE in any game. I've tried some code to make him move but it seems that it glitches, how can I make it so that a key are being hold for a small amount of time and then the next key? For example:

Pressing W for 2 sec, then A for 2 sec, then S for 2 sec and finally D for 2 sec.

Here's my code and I would like if someone helps me with it because I don't understand most of the lines :P

```
int sleepBetween = 50;

if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD1))
        {
            std::cout << "Working..." << endl;

            SHORT key;
            UINT mappedkey;

            // Loop

            while (true)
            {
                INPUT input = {};
                key = VkKeyScan('w');

                mappedkey = MapVirtualKey(LOBYTE(key), 0);
                input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
                input.ki.wScan = mappedkey;

                SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
                Sleep(10);

                input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
                SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

                Sleep(sleepBetween);

                key = VkKeyScan('a');

                mappedkey = MapVirtualKey(LOBYTE(key), 0);
                input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
                input.ki.wScan = mappedkey;

                SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
                Sleep(10);

                input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
                SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

                Sleep(sleepBetween);

                key = VkKeyScan('s');

                mappedkey = MapVirtualKey(LOBYTE(key), 0);
                input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
                input.ki.wScan = mappedkey;

                SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
                Sleep(10);

                input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
                SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

                Sleep(sleepBetween);

                Sleep(sleepBetween);

                key = VkKeyScan('d');

                mappedkey = MapVirtualKey(LOBYTE(key), 0);
                input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
                input.ki.wScan = mappedkey;

                SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
                Sleep(10);

                input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
                SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

                Sleep(sleepBetween);

                // Stop with NUM 2
                if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD2))
                {
                    std::cout << "Stopped!" << endl;
                    break;
                }
```

Comment: If you hold the key for 2 seconds you want the sprite to move for two seconds or are you asking something else? Side note: Writing raw win32 code is a hell of a way to get into writing games. Consider learning the basics with a higher-level framework like... Smurf. I don't know what the cool kids are using these days, but [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) did a good job of living up to the S in its name without making me feel like an idiot for using it.

Comment: What's this got to do with macros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget that it was about a game it's just a macros. It's design was to press a key and that's it.

I fixed it by making a method for holding a key and then recalling it for each key I wanted.

```
    void HoldKey(char keyToHold, double repeatingTime)
{
    SHORT key;
    UINT mappedkey;
    INPUT input;

    key = VkKeyScan(keyToHold);
    mappedkey = MapVirtualKey(LOBYTE(key), 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < repeatingTime; i++)
    {
        input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY; // Press Key
        input.ki.wScan = mappedkey;

        SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

        Sleep(100);

        input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // Releaase Key
        SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
    }
```

And I recalled it in my main method:

```
HoldKey('w', repeatingTime);
            HoldKey('a', repeatingTime);
            HoldKey('s', repeatingTime);
            HoldKey('d', repeatingTime);
```